# Why doesn't my scrollbar work?

Tags: html, scrollbar

Why doesn't my scrollbar work? At other pages I used the same code and it worked.

[Here](http://swohnzimmer.at/kontakt.html) it works fine but [here](http://swohnzimmer.at/events.html) it does not. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked both website just add the below code after center tag also close it from your working link to non working link it will work

```
<main id="top-nav">
```

and remove this from above center tag `<div style="overflow:scroll">`

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem!! :)